# ¿Porque no funciona este codigo python (problema con funciones)?

Tags: python, funciones

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio de funciones en que tengo que hacer que el usuario cargue números y de acuerdo a esos números calcular cuantos eran divisibles por cuatro, el mayor de los impares, cuantas veces se ingreso el primero y cuantas veces se ingreso 1,2,3. Mi problema es que el código que hice no funciona ya que no me da los resultados correctos, creo que principalmente es porque el contador que uso es local y necesito uno global pero no lo tengo muy claro.

Este es el código.

```
def divisible_4 (num):
    num_div_4 = 0
    if num % 4 == 0:
        num_div_4 += 1
    return num_div_4

def mayor_impar(num_ing):
    may_imp = 0
    impar = 0
    if num_ing % 2 == 0:
        pass
    else:
        impar += num_ing
    if impar > may_imp:
        may_imp += impar
    return may_imp

def primer_num(num, cant_num):
    prim_num = 0
    cant = 0
    if cant_num == 1:
        prim_num += num
    if num == prim_num:
        cant += 1
    return cant

def sucesion(num):
    num_1 = False
    sec_123 = False
    sucesion123 = 0
    if num == 1:
        num_1 = True
        sec_123 = False
    elif num == 2 and num_1:
        sec_123 = True
    elif num == 3 and sec_123:
        sucesion123 += 1
    return sucesion123

def menu():
    num_ing = 0
    cant_num = 0
    num = int(input('Ingrese numeros(termina con cero): '))
    while num != 0:
        num_ing += num
        cant_num += 1

        num = int(input('Ingrese numeros(termina con cero): '))

    num_4 = divisible_4(num_ing)
    impar = mayor_impar(num)
    primero_ingresado = primer_num(cant_num, num)
    suc = sucesion(num)

    print('\nNumeros divisibles por cuatro', num_4,
          '\nmayor impar es', impar,
          '\nSe repitio', primero_ingresado, 'veces el primer ingresado',
          '\nSe ingreso', suc, ' veces el 1,2,3')

menu()
```

Comment: cuáles son los resultados correctos esperados y qué es lo que estás obteniendo en su lugar?

Comment: Me parece que estás entendiendo mal la tarea que estás haciendo. Te recomiendo leer sobre **listas** en Python, ya que al sumar el número ingresado a otro número (en este caso, num_ing, que comienza con cero), solo le vas a sumar el número ingresado, no los estás "guardando". Es decir, vas a hacer 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 = 6 en lugar de guardar [1, 2, 3] que creo que es lo que quieres.

Comment: @DannyTalent Claro eso es lo que quiero que hacer, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te hace falta a ti es una lista, esta es una estructura de datos que permite guardar diversos tipos de datos. Tampoco necesitas variables globales, lo único que necesitas es pasarle un parámetro a la función. Recordemos que los parámetros son "alias" que tendrá algún dato dentro de nuestra función, es decir que si en nuestra función definimos un parámetro `x`, esa `x` puede tomar cualquier valor al momento de ser llamada nuestra función, pero dentro de nuestra función trabajaremos con `x`.

He simplificado todas tus funciones para reducir el código.

```py
#todas las funciones recibirán la lista de números

def divisible_4(nums):
    #con len contamos la cantidad de elementos de la lista
    return len([n for n in nums if n%4==0]) #generamos una lista solo cuyos elementos deben cumplir la condicion

def mayor_impar(nums):
    #retornamos el elemento máximo de la lista
    return max([n for n in nums if n%2!=0])

def sucecion(nums):
    #convertimos la lista en una cadena
    nums = ",".join([f"{n}" for n in nums])
    return nums.count("1,2,3") #contamos las veces que se repite la serie

def primer_num(nums):
    return nums.count(nums[0]) #contamos las veces que se repite el primer elemento


def menu():
    num_ing = []
    cant_num = 0
    num = int(input('Ingrese numeros(termina con cero): '))
    while num != 0:
        num_ing.append(num)
        cant_num += 1

        num = int(input('Ingrese numeros(termina con cero): '))

    num_4 = divisible_4(num_ing)
    impar = mayor_impar(num_ing)
    primero_ingresado = primer_num(num_ing)
    suc = sucecion(num_ing)

    #utilizamos los f-strings
    print(f"""Numeros divisibles por cuatro {num_4}
    mayor impar es {impar},
    Se repitio {primero_ingresado} veces el primer ingresado
    Se ingreso {suc} veces el 1,2,3""")

menu()
```

**Probamos**

```
Ingrese numeros(termina con cero): 1
Ingrese numeros(termina con cero): 10
Ingrese numeros(termina con cero): 12
Ingrese numeros(termina con cero): 1
Ingrese numeros(termina con cero): 2
Ingrese numeros(termina con cero): 3
Ingrese numeros(termina con cero): 1
Ingrese numeros(termina con cero): 2
Ingrese numeros(termina con cero): 3
Ingrese numeros(termina con cero): 7
Ingrese numeros(termina con cero): 0

Numeros divisibles por cuatro 1
    mayor impar es 7,
    Se repitio 3 veces el primer ingresado
    Se ingreso 2 veces el 1,2,3
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de explicarme todo, estoy perdido con este tema, gracias.

Comment: si algo no te quedó claro avisame y lo explicaré a fondo y si la respuesta te sirvió no olvides marcarla como aceptada :D